# How to automatically deploy when push code like Heroku on my server

Tags: git, heroku, devops

Like Heroku, I want my code be compiled and deployed when I push it to repo by git, and compile messages be showed on console. Not like CI tool that push code normally and show error later over email or on a dashboard.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do this [via a Git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), specifically the `post-receive` one.

> This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack[1] when it reacts to git push and updates reference(s) in its repository. It executes on the remote repository once after all the refs have been updated.
>
> Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to git send-pack on the other end, so you can simply echo messages for the user.